# Redirect to another route with data Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-5.8

Good day everyone. I am encountering an error in my code. I am trying to redirect to another route and passing data with it.

**Controller code:**

```
    return redirect()->route('customer.success', compact('data'));
```

**Route:**

```
    Route::get('success-customer', 'CustomerController@showSuccess')->name('customer.success');
```

**Blade:**

```
    Your assistant: {{Session::get($data['assistant'])}}
```

Now my error is, it shows the error of `undefined data` yet I used the `compact` function.
Answers and advices are highly appreciated!

Comment: Please try to check whether you have data in compact?

Answer (score 2):

In laravel 5.8 you can do the following:

`return redirect('login')->with('data',$data);`

in blade file The data will store in session not in variable.

`{{ Session::get('data') }}`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
return redirect()->route('profile', ['id' => 1]);
```

To redirect to any controller, use this code

```
return redirect()->action('DefaultController@index');
```

If you want to send data using redirect, try to use this code

```
return Redirect::route('customer.success)->with( ['data' => $data] );
```

To read the data in blade, use this one

```
// in PHP
$id = session()->get( 'data' );

// in Blade
{{ session()->get( 'data' ) }}
```

Check [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/redirects) for more info

Comment: This works, why does it show no data after I refresh the page?

Answer (score 0):

TRy this

```
  return Redirect::route('customer.success')->with(['data'=>$data]);
```

In blade

```
Session::get('data');
```